# Catch all the images in a URL and move to a Slide

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get multiple images from an online repository from a URL and I do not know where to start. I will create the slide with Picasso, but from there I do not know how to pull all the images from the link.

An example would be all the images on that page: http://www.readmangaonline.org/manga/one-piece/902/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) to scrap images form webpage.

To use JSoup on Android add this to your gradle file

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
```

Then create an AsyncTask to fetch webpage content

```
class ImageScrapAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
        if (document != null) {
            Elements imgElements = document.select("img");
            List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Element element : imgElements) {
                String image = element.attr("data-src");
                /*Note data-src is used instead of src, as example 
                you provided uses lazy loading and has image file 
                url inside data-src attribute. You may need to use 
                src for other pages. */
                Log.d("IMAGE_URL", image);
                images.add(image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can initiate AsyncTask as

```
String url = "http://www.readmangaonline.org/manga/one-piece/902/1";
new ImageScrapAsyncTask().execute(url);
```

Now you have list of image urls in `images` List inside onPostExecute of AsyncTask.

Comment: Where does this select and attr?

Comment: select and attr are methods from JSoup, select is used to select elements with tag while attr gets value of that attribue from element.

Comment: Have you added JSoup to your gradle file ?

Comment: Was. I had missed something.

Doubt. I study shortly so I'm kind of lost ...
I created the class ImageScrapAsyncTask, same as you wrote.

Now I call it here onCreate?
String url = "http://www.readmangaonline.org/manga/one-piece/902/1";
new ImageScrapAsyncTask (). execute (url);

Comment: Yes ! Also don't forget to provide internet permission on manifest.

Comment: 1) Use full URL : http://unionmangas.site/leitor/One_Piece/901
2) Replace data-src inside attr with src for this.
3) Image url returned starts with // so add http: at start of image url

Comment: Thanks, man. Do you have any tutorials to study a bit about this?

Comment: Could you give me one more help? In case I have already created a ViewPager. It's working, now I just need to put the images in Picasso.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900035/passing-jsoup-images-to-picasso

Comment: @OliverDamon I have answered your question !