# Passing JSoup images to Picasso

Tags: java, android

A user recently helped me get the images with JSoup. I made a ViewPager with Picasso and created a Test String [] and it is working.

Now I would like to pull those images that are in JSoup and put in picasso.

Could anyone help?

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String url = "http://www.readmangaonline.org/manga/one-piece/902/1";
    private String[] imageUrls = new String[]{
        "http://i999.mangapanda.com/one-piece/902/one-piece-10510603.jpg",
        "http://i999.mangapanda.com/one-piece/902/one-piece-10510603.jpg"
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new ImageScrapAsyncTask().execute(url);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

```html
class ImageScrapAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
        if (document != null) {
            Elements imgElements = document.select("img");
            List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Element element : imgElements) {
                String image = element.attr("data-src");
                Log.d("IMAGE_URL", image);
                images.add(image);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Adapter: https://hastebin.com/vibecilugi.scala

Comment: please please don't put this in an async task. this code is a memory leak, and a crash waiting to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set adapter inside onPostExecute (after data is available.)

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
        if (document != null) {
            Elements imgElements = document.select("img");
            List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Element element : imgElements) {
                String image = element.attr("data-src");
                Log.d("IMAGE_URL", image);
                if(image!=null && !image.equals("")){
                    images.add(image);
                }
            }

            String[] imgArray = images.toArray(new String[images.size()]);
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, imgArray);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Note : Make viewPager global.

Comment: Sorry, but where do I move to stay global?

Comment: Inside MainActivity alnog with String url.

Comment: I tried here, but I'm doing something wrong.
https://image.prntscr.com/image/_kKOIRmpQPmgvcdnaa1Elg.png
http://prntscr.com/jw1o57

Comment: Move ViewPager viewPager to top along with url (above onCreate). Also keep viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager) without ViewPager infront of viewpager ( as we  have declared it above)

Comment: Replace this with MainActivity.this.

Comment: For viewPager issue move ImageScrapAsyncTask class inside MainActivity.

Comment: I tried the way you said: https://hastebin.com/dofuxeyavi.scala
But there he gave an error in this line here: http://prntscr.com/jw1wi1

Comment: I changed the code, but it is not displaying the image on the slide. And shows no error.

Comment: Which url are you using to fetch image ?

Comment: Is not there something missing here? Because it has the name image and images.
https://hastebin.com/asasenesof.vbs

Adapter: https://hastebin.com/goporugati.scala

Comment: Man, I'm trying here. I still can not, did you see it?

Comment: That's not the problem. We need to do the following ...
Pass the link of these images to a String []
To stay like this: [http://teste.com/image1.png, http://teste.com/image2.png]

Comment: You have to put it in a String [].
I tried to split but it did not look cool.

Comment: String [] imgArray is string array converted from string list.

Comment: Strange that with it is not working. Did you take a look at my adapter?

Comment: Log length of imgArray just before we pass it to ViewPager . I think it may be empty.

Comment: Yes it is. What I do?

Comment: I tried to change something in him but I did not know what.

Comment: Thanks, man. I was forgetting to put:
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);